# Equivalent condition of "$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ has exactly one solution".

Tags: abstract-algebra

Equivalent condition of "$Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ has exactly one solution" is "$\Delta=B^2-4AC=0$".

Now we turn to the equation $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$. Do we have discriminant for it? How to relate $A,B,...,F$ so that it has exactly one solution $(x,y)$? Thank you.

p.s. I searched wiki, by defining $\Delta=B^2-4AC=0$ again, $\Delta>0,=0,<0$ correspond to ellipse, circle, parabola, etc. But it says nothing about the above case.

Comment: Over the complex numbers, a nonconstant polynomial in two variables has infinitely many solutions (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632714/prove-that-a-complex-valued-polynomial-over-two-variables-has-infinitely-many-ze) for more on this.)  The question of whether there is only one (or are only finitely many) solutions $(x,y)$ with $x,y \in \mathbb R$ -- as in the case of the equation $x^2+y^2=0$  -- is more subtle. I do not know of a "discriminant-like" criterion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an ellipse of dimensions zero, centered at $(p,q)$.  Note I have $2B$ where you have $B$.
$$A(x-p)^2+2B(x-p)(y-q)+C(y-q)^2=0\\B^2<AC\\
Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2-(2Ap+2Bq)x-(2Cq+2Bp)y+Ap^2+2Bpq+Cq^2=0\\
F=\left[\begin{array}{cc}p&q\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}A&B\\B&C\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}p\\q\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c}D&E\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}A&B\\B&C\end{array}\right]^{-1}
\left[\begin{array}{c}D\\E\end{array}\right]/4$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections